# How to export image into higher-level directory than that of the file producing it

Tags: julia

Because I'm keeping the `.tex` mark-up for a paper in the same git repo as all the software required to produce the figures needed, I have the following directory structure:

```
+- code
|   +- script.jl
+- figures
|   +- figure.eps
+- ...
```

If `script.jl` exports `figure.eps`, is it possible to export it to the `figures` folder directly? Or is the highest level I can export to that of the script itself (i.e., `code`)?

Apologies if this is a silly question; as you can tell from the context in which the question arises, I'm more of a researcher than a programmer, and searching for the keywords that came to mind didn't yield anything helpful.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Unless some file/directory permissions intervene, using the filename `joinpath("..","figures","figure.eps")` will get you to the location of `figure.eps` you described. Note the `".."` which takes you to the parent directory. And do `?joinpath` in the REPL for more info. The need for `joinpath` is because different OSes treat filenames a little differently. Also, check `pwd()` which returns the current directory. The filename given in the comment is relative to location of `script.jl` but you may be in some other current directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can export your figures to any location on your computer that you have access to. As Dan Getz mentioned `joinpath` is your friend when specifying the directory so you don't have to worry about using different OS's.

Also important to consider is where you are calling the script from. If I am in `path/to/code` and execute `julia script.jl` then I can use `joinpath("..","figures","figure.eps")` just fine because the path will be calculated from your current working directory.

However if you want to specify the path relative to the location of script.jl (so you can call the script from anywhere) then you can use the `@__DIR__` macro which returns the absolute path of the directory which contains the file where the macro was called.

`joinpath(@__DIR__,"..","figures","figures.eps")`